# C# How to reload a form with dynamically created items

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

[Image of program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AyxW9.png)

My main form dynamically creates List boxes for each entry in a list. By clicking the top right button I get a tiny form to make a new entry. If I close the form a new textbox should be created, however I can't just call the method that creates the listboxes because it will draw duplicates. Is there a way to refresh the whole form without closing it and making a new one?

Textbox code

```
foreach (Uitslag u in geselecteerdeVerkiezing.uitslagen)
{
    CreateDynamicTextBox(x, y, u);
    UpdatePositionManager(ref x, ref y, ref PositionManager);
}

private void CreateDynamicTextBox(int x, int y, Uitslag u)
{
    TextBox textBox = new TextBox();
    textBox.Location = new Point(x, y);
    textBox.Size = new Size(220, 100);
    textBox.Multiline = true;
    textBox.ReadOnly = true;
    textBox.Text = ("Verkiezing: " + geselecteerdeVerkiezing.Naam + Environment.NewLine + "Uitslag: " + u.Naam + Environment.NewLine + "Aantal zetels: " + +geselecteerdeVerkiezing.AantalZetels + Environment.NewLine + "Zetels voor meerderheid: " + geselecteerdeVerkiezing.Meerderheid + Environment.NewLine + "Aantal deelnemende partijen: " + u.DeelnemendePartijen.Count);
    textBox.Name = u.Naam;

    textBox.MouseClick += new MouseEventHandler(textBox_Click);
    this.Controls.Add(textBox);
}
```

Comment: So... deleting the existing controls you mean?

Comment: @EpicKip thought so as well, but hard to get it

Comment: Looks like you're creating TextBoxes, not ListBoxes.

Comment: Can I in a way delete all existing textbox controlls? this is the first time I'm working with dynamicly created objects

Comment: @TomLimpens If english is hard for you you can post a comment in dutch, I can read/translate.

Comment: @LarsTech yes, my bad. that's a typing error.

Comment: @EpicKip English isn't hard for me, I just make alot of typing mistakes

Comment: ``this.Controls.Clear();`` should be what you are looking for. I guess, but watch out this will propably also remove your buttons. So you should have a own Container for your textBoxes and clear this Container and add textBoxes to this.

Comment: @RandRandom won't that also delete the buttons?
ah didn't see the edit yet.

Comment: @RandRandom That will not dispose of the controls.

Comment: @TomLimpens see edit to comment

Comment: Can you reuse controls, or do they need to be recreated every time?

Comment: @LarsTech who cares about Memory leaks when developing with winforms, try to find a Windows pc that has less than 16GB nowadays. *just (half) kidding*

Comment: @RandRandom Because I care about teaching someone what is right and wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete all textbox's I think you can just do this (no time to test):

```
var textBoxes = this.Controls.Cast<Control>().Where(r => r is TextBox).ToArray();
foreach (var textBox in textBoxes)
{
    textBox.Dispose();
}
```

You could also check them by name in the `.Where()` or in the `ForEach` itself.

Comment: That will not dispose of the controls.

Comment: @LarsTech Thanks forgot ;)

Comment: You would have to put a `.ToArray()` at the end of your textBoxes declaration because you can't modify an enumeration during a for-each.  Currently, your code wouldn't remove *all* the controls in the list.  You can also remove the `Controls.Remove(textBox)` line since Dispose will do that for you.

Comment: I think this will work, but I found a deeper issue while testing this. 
I'm giving an object with this form wich has a list of the objects who create the Textboxes so I'll need to update that list before I can update my form. Thanks though it apears to work for the existing objects in the list.

Comment: @TomLimpens If this solved the issue asked in the question please accept so other people can use it